# How to add alt text to an image inserted from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an html file with this line:

```
<div >%%GLOBAL_ProductThumb%%</div>
```

and live it generates this:

```
<img width="200px" height="200px" alt="" src="[I removed the URL]">
```

In a PHP file, I see the variable being assigned on this line

```
$GLOBALS['ProductThumb'] = ImageThumb200x200($rowimg['imagefile']);
```

I don't know much about PHP, but how can I add fill the "alt" property with text? In what step/where would this occur? If this were Java I wouldn't have a problem figuring out how to set the property of an object, but I'm not quite sure what's going on here. If the context helps, it's custom shopping cart software designed for our business.

Comment: The problem with custom software is that random people on the internet know nothing about it. You're much better off contacting the developer of that software. - I'm telling you this because   `ImageThumb200x200` is not part of the standard API and a quick google search couldnt bring up anything either.

Comment: Well I don't think the solution is really specific to this custom software. I just want to know how to add an "alt" property to an image embedded via a PHP variable. Or at least how other people do it. I'm basically wishing for "$GLOBALS['ProductThumb'].setAltText("Something");" if that makes any sense...

Comment: @Xenalin: Yes the solution _is_ specific to it. PHP has no standard means to add some HTML attribute to a HTML tag. All you can do is build the HTML code as a string, then printing out the string. Which is something your software does by grabbing some other variables, giving you little direct influence on the generated code.

Comment: It looks like your template system translates %%hash_var%% to the string $hash['var']. So after populating the value with ImageThumb200x200() you could do a `$GLOBALS['ProductThumb'] = preg_replace('/^<img/', '/<img alt="whatever"/', $GLOBALS['ProductThumb']);` It's hackish, but should do what you need.

Comment: @Julian that was the information I needed-that ImageThumb200x200 builds an html string. If you make that an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @JasonM that looks like it would've worked but Julian's info was more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has no standard means to add some HTML attribute to a HTML tag. All you can do is build the HTML code as a string, then printing out the string. Which is something your software does by grabbing some other variables, giving you little direct influence on the generated code.

That said, the only thing you can do is inspecting what exactly all those custom functions are returning. If you are lucky, you find the exact HTML code that will land on the page in the end somewhere. From there, it's just a matter of programmatically searching and replacing before handing the final string further down the line.

Comment: It led to this: 
$imageThumb .= '<img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="" height="200px" width="200px" />';
I added "'.$GLOBALS['ProductName'].'" in there! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A jquery hack can do that for you. If you can penetrate that third party app. You can embed a Jquery code that can take care of it on DOM Ready event.
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img[width='200px'][height='200px']").prop("alt", "Your ALT value");
    })
</script>
```